# Windows command line additional quotation mark in parameter in Golang

Tags: go

I would like to write a batch helper in Windows (Windows 8.1 with Go 1.3.1) to using exiftool.exe.

The reason I to run command line in Go is I tried to access some EXIF information which I retrieval from  other web side. I just want to write back to picture EXIF.

Here is my code segment.

```
        str_abs, _ := filepath.Abs(target_path)
        str_title := fmt.Sprintf("-title=\"%s\"", ext_str)
        stdout, err := exec.Command("cmd", "/c", "exiftool.exe", str_title, "-E", str_abs).Output()
```

However I found there always a addtional quote  will in parameter so the result will identical with:

```
exiftool.exe -title=""TITLE"" -E TARGET_FILE
```

Any idea how it happen? or any suggestion for how to handle parameter like this.

Note:

- The reason I separate parameter and string combine it again, because command line need use unicode string such as Chinese String.
- exiftool.exe only works on command line with "&#%d;" code with Chinese Character in Windows so I do more handle for this.
- How ever it also happen error if I use non-unicode such as (title shows '1234' not 1234)

  ```
      stdout, err := exec.Command("cmd", "/c", "exiftool.exe", "-title", "1234", str_abs).Output()
  ```
- error code:Run command eror: exit status 1.

-----Update on 2014/09/10 for @VonC-------------------------------------------------

Hi VonC,

I tried to do the same thing as your provided code, but it not works for me.
I am curious about command line code page, I tried it in 477(US) 950 (Big5) both not work for me.

There is two thing I would like to discuss.

- The Chinese word must change to &#%d; otherwise it will wrong display.

  - ex: 世界 -> 世界 Check this [wrong encoding picture](https://www.flickr.com/photos/evanlin1007/15008091029/) for encode display error.
- Even I tried it, but it still display extra " in my picture title.

  - Refer this [extra quotation picture](https://www.flickr.com/photos/evanlin1007/15194760435/).
- My code sample as follow:

  ```
  output, err := exec.Command(`d:\exiftool.exe`,
  `-title="test 2&#19990;&#30028;"`,
  //If it not trasnfer from 世界 -> &#19990;&#30028;  it could not display correctly.
  "-E", "test.jpg").CombinedOutput()
  if err != nil {
      fmt.Println(err.Error())
  }
  fmt.Println(string(output))
  ```

Comment: passing str_title to exec.Command will pass it to the program as `"-title=\"xx\""`, now if exiftool expects that then you should just use `fmt.Sprintf("-title=%s", ext_str)`, it will automatically split after the `=` without the quotes. Also please paste any errors you got.

Comment: My suspicion is that this Command trying to apply automatic quotes *for Windows/Microsoft-broken single-string command passing* (this is not needed on an \*IX system). Compare with passing the command as a *single* string - eg. `"cmd /c exiftool.exe -title=\"blah\" -E foo"`.

Comment: Why are you trying to run `exiftool.exe` via `cmd.exe` (and get all the shell-pasring hassles with it) instead of just running it directly (and hence having a way to just specify positional parameters without having to think about quoting)?

Comment: Hi @kostix, I could not get your point, would you mind to specific more detail? How to run it directly? Did you mean run it without using Go? Because I need read extra title/description from files to update it into EXIF.

Comment: @EvanLin I have run it directly, and it works. You don't even need `&#19990;`. But again, a shell is the wrong medium to see the result.

Comment: @VonC Thank you. Actually I use Windows File Explorer and Flickr to double confirm the result. It could not work without &$19900;.  Would you please to provide your environment to help me to do more investigation? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested:

```
output, err := exec.Command(`c:\prgs\exiftool-9.70\exiftool.exe`,
    `-title="test 2 世界"`,
    "-E", "test.jpg").CombinedOutput()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
}
fmt.Println(string(output))
```

And it seems to work just fine.
Note that [`exec.CombinedOutput()`](http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.CombinedOutput) allows to see a bit more than just "`exit status 1`" in case of a problem.

A second call will dispay all EXIF matadata:

```
exec.Command(`c:\prgs\exiftool-9.70\exiftool.exe`, "test.jpg").CombinedOutput()
```

The title is the expected `test 2 世界`.

Comment: Thanks, but it still not work for me. Check my update as above.

Comment: @EvanLin on which shell are you seeing this error? A cmd shell won't ever be able to display them right, but if you redirect the output to a file, and edit that file, you will see the *exact* unicode content that you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

fmt.Printf("%q", "somestring") => "somestring"

Comment: Hi Dave, Because I need to write big5 code using exiftool.exe. If I don't transfer it to &#19990; it will display error word. Thank you.